# Equivalence classes of function f: A -> B

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, equivalence-relations

If we let f: A -> B be a function and A, B be two non-empty sets.

There exists a equivalence relation definied as

> a ~ b ⇔ f(a) = f(b) for all a,b ∈ A

I am asked to describe the equivalence classes

My textbook says the answer is

> Let A* $  =f^{-1}(y)$ then the equivalence classes corresponding to ~
>   are {A* : y ∈ B}.

I am having a bit of trouble understanding what the answer means. I can't really see how the f(a) = f(b) condition is being taken into consideration when constructing the equivalence classes.

Is the answer simply saying that the preimage of every element in B has it's own equivalence class in A? Would that mean that every equivalence class only consists of one element?

Thank you

Comment: In this context, $f^{-1}(y)$, is a _set_ of elements, not an element. Note that $f$ need not be invertible. Take a simple example: Let $f(x)=x^2$. For this example, we have $f^{-1}(9)=\{-3,3\}$.

Comment: Aha, so y could be a set of elements in B, I did not realize that. In your example, -3 and 3 clearly both map to 9, so I see now an equivalence class could consist of more than one element. Does A* represents one equivalence class and {A* : y ∈ B} the collection of them all, essentially forming all of A?

Comment: In this context, $y$ is a single element of $B$. On the other hand, $f^{-1}(y)$ is the set of all elements of $A$ that map to $y$. So for the example $f(x)=x^2$, regarded as a function fro $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, one equivalence class is $\{0\}$, and all other equivalence classes are sets of two elements, such as $\{-3,3\}$.

Comment: As another example, letting $A=B=\mathbb{R}$, consider the function $f:A\to B$ given by $f(x)=\lfloor{x}\rfloor$. Under the specified equivalence relation,  which elements of $A$ are equivalent to the element $0$? Said differently, the equivalence class containing $0$ is what set?

Comment: As to your question about the equivalence classes "forming all of $A$", yes, the union of the equivalence classes is all of $A$. Each element of $A$ is equivalent to itself, and to all other elements of $A$ which have the same $f$-value (i.e., yield the same result when fed as input to $f$).

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for your effort, I think I got it know! Then would it be true that every equivalence class consisted of only one element if f was an injective function ?

Comment: Yes, if $f$ is injective, then every equivalence class would be a singleton set.